# datagridview CellEndEdit fires twice

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having a bit of an issue with the datagridview's `CellEndEdit` event. While I understand the concept of what the issue actually is, any attempt at circumventing it seems to fail.

Basically, I have a datagridview, in the `CellEndEdit` event, I make a check against the database to make sure the entry is not a duplicate. If it is, I prompt the user with a messagebox to tell them they can't enter duplicates, I then change the value back to its original state/value programmatically, and return the cell to an "Edit" state.

My understanding is that the fact that i'm changing the value programatically is why the event fires twice. To circumvent, I set a flag upon first entering the event, then prompt + set + re-edit, then set the flag to false. This does not work... can anyone tell me why or how I can make this happen?

Here's the event code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["Name"].ColumnIndex)
    {
        if(!this.CellBeingEdited)
        {
            string NewName = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Name"].Value.ToString();
            //-== DATABASE CODE REMOVED ==-
            bool IsDuplicate = ...;
            if(IsDuplicate)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot have duplicate item names at this level!");
                this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Name"];
                this.CellBeingEdited = true;
                this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = this.LastEditedRowName;
                this.CellBeingEdited = false;
                this.dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit of code does not fire twice when I edit a value in a row :

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {
        string test = "test";
        if (this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == test)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];
            this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = "not test";
            this.dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Perhaps are you calling the event elsewhere?

Comment: same problem... and now it also fires every time the data is binded, the form loads, or the grid refreshes...

Comment: Are you saying the cell validating fires twice every validation?

Comment: no... i am saying that it fires all the time... when the form loads, when the form is shown, when the databinding is done, when the grid UI refreshes, when a value changes, etc... if i use this event, i will have to catch and flag every single instance where the event fires and escape that, i really only want to check this and perform logic when the cell content is finished being edited.

Comment: I shall modify my answer.

Comment: Remove the event-listener when the form initializes like this: `this.dataGridView1.CellValidating -= dataGridView1_CellValidating;`. Once the table is filled set the event-listener again: `this.dataGridView1.CellValidating += dataGridView1_CellValidating;`

Comment: i would have to do that for every instance where this event fires though... a bit counter productive... i count 5 places where i would have to do this.

Comment: Are you validating your row by pressing enter?

Comment: For me clicking out fires the event once and tabbing / pressing enter fires it twice.  That means the double firing issue is probably because tabbing / pressing enter enters another cell.

Comment: do you mean on the CellEndEdit or the CellValidating event?

Comment: The CellEndEdit Event

Comment: Let me test your new solution... since i am reverting back to the original, that is a very good conditional test. I will accept if it works every time. Thanks!

Comment: Do not forget to validate the value of the cell first (check if it is null) or it will throw an error when it is

Comment: thank you! works great! :) I can finally move on! :)